# How do I add a video to a PDF file?

Tags: video, pdf, pdftk

Adobe Acrobat allows to embed videos in PDF files. Is there a way to do this with a free tool like `pdftk`?
I have several slides in my pdf and I would like to add an `mp4` or `webm` file among those slides.

Comment: And to follow up, how do you then view the video in the PDF, or does it require an external viewer (and how does that work?)